# Romanian documents after marriage in Germany

Tags: germany, marriage, documentation, romanian-citizens

I'm getting married with my fiancée, who is a Romanian girl. Since we live in Germany (I'm not German either - I'm Italian), we chose to marry under German law, therefore we also chose her to get my surname.

Since she will change her surname, she will need to reapply for each document she has (I guess by the consulate).

- Does the Romanian consulate in Germany accept a marriage certificate in German (apparently they do, but that consulate is not famous to be very precise about the info they give)?
- Can she write her residency here in Germany on her ID?
- Do contracts and other documents made here in Germany automatically update, or do we need to notify every single entity?

Comment: You may be able to get a copy of your marriage certificate in Romanian if that registar offers that service (some do). It can't hurt to ask. She will not necessarily need to notify every single entity that she has a contract with. As long as she keeps hold of the former documention she used as identity with that entity. Some organizations, such as banks, may have a written requirement in her contract that she notify them of a name change, mostly due to adherence with German law. I very much doubt that anything other than perhaps a few government agencies will 'automatically' update.

Comment: Our "Standesamt" does not provide any document written in Romanian (already asked for it). Are you sure that the Romanian consulate would not retain every document of hers that exhibits her previous name?

Comment: @Nolder130884, I'm not sure what you mean with the Romanian consulate retain every document. Certainly they will keep records of every service they have provided her. That will be irrespective of her name. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, if they release a new ID / a new passport, I think they will take and destroy the old ones...

Comment: No. They will usually stamp it as cancelled and cut off the corners or hole punch it, something like that. They don't normally destroy them.

Comment: @Noldor130884 Most countries return cancelled passports to the bearer after cancellation.  I'm not sure about ID cards, and I don't know about Romania's policies or practices.

Comment: Oh...Okay, I was totally ignorant about that.

Comment: Just saying: I got an "international" marriage certificate from the German registry office with translations into ten languages. I don't know if Romanian was among them (I suppose it started with German, English, French, Spanish, Italian and then five more) but since the EU has grown they might have more languages now. Maybe you need to ask for the right thing. They won't have "Romanian", but they should have "German" and "International".

Comment: Passports often contain visas, that's why they should be returned. A visa in a passport should remain valid even if the passport has become invalid (but check before you rely on that information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Romanian citizen, your wife is obliged to do what is called a "transcription" of her German marriage certificate in Romanian civil status registers. She can go to www.econsulat.ro to do it for free at the nearest Consulate, or use a professional like www.romaniandocuments.net.
The German certificate will only be accepted directly if it is a "Multilingual Extract" (Mehrsprachiges Auszug). If not, it will have to be Apostilled and Translated authentically into Romanian before presentation.
After transcription she will get a corresponding Romanian marriage certificate, and a new Romanian passport on her new name.

Regarding the ID, she cannot get a foreign address on Romanian ID cards, but she can apply for a "Passport for Romanian Citizens Domiciled Abroad". To do this, www.econsulat.ro is also the solution. In this case, her passport will state "Domicile: Germany", and then she can use the German ID / Residence card to prove her exact address.